# Error in trying to access the magento from a remote machine connected in same network?

Tags: php, magento

I actually wrote few files for magento extension which provides pages with layout.But when I access these from different system I the page is loading like a basic html version without any layout..

What might be the error and how to overcome this..

Thank you,

Comment: You may want to develop your question by adding more information like, what code, what is the desired behaviour and how does it exactly fail in matching this desired behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While installing Magento there will be a step where we perform database connection.There we have an option for base url.There you change the value to `http://yourip/magento`.